# Refresh the likes counter without reloading the Ajax page

Tags: ajax, laravel

It was necessary to write a method for salting posts in php and decorate the whole thing with ajax so that the page would not reload. The method was written, likes are put, but for the changes to be visible, you need to reload the page. I suspect I made a mistake in the area of success

This is part of the post, you need to update the button with `id = "likebtn {{$ post-> id}}"`

html form

```
<form action="{{route('likePost', ['id' => Auth::user()->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}" method="POST" id="likepostform{{$post->id}}">
    @csrf @method('PATCH')
    <button data-id="{{$post->id}}" id="likebtn{{$post->id}}" type="submit" class="likebtn button-delete-post-2">
        <img src="{{asset('img/footer/like.png')}}" class="img-fluid" width="25"><small class="text-muted mr-4">{{$post->likepost}}</small>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" id="user_id">
</form>
```

Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click",".likebtn",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
        var user_id = $("#user_id").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "id"+user_id+"/"+id+"/like",
            type: 'PATCH',
            data: {_token: token, id: id, user_id: user_id},
            success: function (data){
                $("#likebtn"+id).html($(data).find("#likebtn"+id).html());
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is `data` here ? Also you have 2 ids with same name ?

Comment: id => post id and user_id => user id

Comment: okay so what is `$(data)` here ? which element you are accessing by this that ?